# Showing that $1200x_1^2-400x_2+202>0$ given that $x_1^2-x_2>-0.005$

Tags: inequality, solution-verification

I am trying to construct a simple argument to verify that the inequality $$1200x_1^2-400x_2+202>0$$ is true, given that $x_1^2-x_2>-0.005$. My argument is as follows:

\begin{align}
1200x_1^2-400x_2+202&\geq400x_1^2-400x_2+202 \\
&=400(x_1^2-x_2)+202 \\
&>400(-0.005)+202 \\
&=200 \\
&>0.
\end{align}
The first inequality follows from the fact that $\alpha x^2\geq \beta x^2$ $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ where $\alpha>\beta$. Is this simple argument valid?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Just the way I would do it.

Comment: It is perfectly ok.

Comment: Except a tiny typo that $400(-0.005)+202\ne 200$

Comment: It does equal $200$.

Comment: it equals $200$ to me

Answer (score 2):

you answer is already neat, just to add you can also do it like this to avoid confusion
$$1200x_{1}^2-400x_{2}+202 > 0$$
$$1200x_{1}^2-400x_{2}+202 + 400x_{1}^2 > 0 +400x_{1}^2$$
but $x_{1}^2-x_{2} > -0.005$, say $\alpha$ is a positive real number
$$x_{1}^2-x_{2} = -0.005 + \alpha $$
$$1200x_{1}^2+202 + 400 \cdot (x_{1}^2 - x_{2} ) > 0 +400x_{1}^2$$
$$1200x_{1}^2+202 + 400 \cdot ( -0.005 + \alpha ) > 0 +400x_{1}^2$$
$$1200x_{1}^2+202 - 2 +400 \alpha >  0 +400x_{1}^2$$
$$1200x_{1}^2 - 400x_{1}^2 + 200 + 400 \alpha > 0  $$
$$800 x_{1}^2 + 200 + 400 \alpha > 0$$
since $\alpha$ is a positive real number and " $x_{1}^2$ " is also a positive number, then the identity is true